# How to handle dynamic amount of parameters on controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm hosting an `iframe` in an ASP.NET MVC View and I have to pass certain parameters to this `iframe`'s `src` url. These are in the form of simple string/string key-value pairs e.g. `http://test.test?param1=value1&param2=value2`.

The goal is for the url of my own controller's action to decide what these parameters will be. Basically something along the lines of:

1. User goes to `http://www.myapp.com/MyController/Index?param1=value1&param2=value2`
2. I receive this in `public ActionResult Index(Dictionary<string, string> dynamicParameters)`
3. On my view, I build the `iframe`'s url based on what `dynamicParameters` contains. If the action gets called with additional parameters, different values, ... these all cleanly get passed to this `iframe`.

I'm having trouble with step 1 and 2. I'm not sure in which format the url should be (I am building this url elsewhere with `Url.Action()` for the record), and I'm not sure how to receive the parameters in my controller's action.

I've tried a couple different approaches with `dynamic`, `dynamic[]`, `Dictionary<string, string>`, ... and have had no luck so far. Is something like this at all possible?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: You could create a custom route handler [external link](https://dotnet-helpers.com/mvc/creating-custom-route-handler-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your parameters are highly dynamic, you don't need to declare them in the signature of the action method -- instead, you can access them via [Request.QueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.7.2). For Url.Action, you can pass a `Dictionary<string, object>` as the route value collection. Any parameters contained within that don't match declared route parameters should be appended to the query string.